# Scheduled data load into Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie

Just wondering what is the best way to bulk load data from various sources into HDFS, mainly from FTP locations / file servers at scheduled times with regular frequency.

I know Sqoop / Oozie combination can be used for RDBMS data. However, wondering what is the best way to load unstructured data into HDFS with a scheduling mechanism.

Comment: I've been researching this lately and there doesn't seem to be a good way - seems like everybody rolls their own code for this or doesn't care about this case at all. I'd love to be proven wrong though!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with shell programming.i can guide with some code

```
 hadoop fs -cp ftp://uname:password@ftp2.xxxxa.com/filename  hdfs://IPofhdfs/user/root/Logs/
```

some points:

```
   1 finding the new files in ftp folder source by comparing  hdfs dest with filenames.
   2 pass the new filename to hdfs copy command.
```

---list out all files in ftp,store list of file to allfiles.txt--

```
  ftp -in ftp2.xxxx.com << SCRIPTEND
  user Luname pass
  lcd /home/Analytics/TempFiles
  ls > AllFiles.txt
  binary
  quit
  SCRIPTEND

  let me know if you need any info
```

Comment: Thanks Sravan, But I am just wondering if there is a better way to do that doing this comparison between source list and the list in HDFS etc.

Comment: in Ftp side,if you have a privilege to move file to downloaded folder.it could be easy thing.